# Remove some files based on filename

Tags: bash

I'm using macOS, creating a Bash script.

I have these files inside some `/path/to/inc/` folder:

```
./lorem-ipsum.php
./dolor-sit.amet.php
./config-prod.php
./enqueue.php
./config.php
./setup.php
./config-uat.php
./config-some-other-thing.php
```

Now I want to get the files that have `config*.php` as name and remove them ***except*** the one named `config-prod.php`, so the folder ends up looking like this:

```
./lorem-ipsum.php
./dolor-sit.amet.php #Still here
./config-prod.php
./enqueue.php
./config.php #Removed
./setup.php
./config-uat.php #Removed
./config-some-other-thing.php #Removed
```

Is there any way to do this using `find` or similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [extended globs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo config!(-prod).php
config-some-other-thing.php config-uat.php config.php
```

and delete the files with

```
rm config!(-prod).php
```

`!(pattern)` matches everything but *`pattern`*.

Answer (score -2):

I tested with linux:

```
find . ! -name 'config-prod.php' -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: This will delete *everything* but `config-prod.php `